# Rewrite URL In joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, redirect

Is it possible to do the following URL rewrite (not redirect) with htaccess?

> mypage.com/en/example/example/index.php **to** mypage.com/en/example

I have also enabled URL rewriting in Joomla config, but I don't know if this has any effect on this.

I tried something like below, but its not working:

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.mypage.com/en/example/example/index.php$ 
http://www.mypage.com/en/example [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?en/example/example/index.php$ en/example [R=301,L]
```

or like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/example/example/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) en/example [R=301,L]
```